# SOPUI - How to Check in Data base?

Tags: database, testing, soap, automated-tests, soapui

I have Req1
after running Req1 some Response will Display

something like

```
 <a:Description>AFGHANISTAN</a:Description>  
               <a:Id>243</a:Id>  
           :  
           :
```

It will Display all countries and IDs
I wanted to check this in DB, 
How I can do this?

Comment: Use the JDBC step: http://www.soapui.org/jdbc/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

First get your values from response

```
 def groovyUtils = com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

    def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("TestStepName#Response")
    def descriptionFromResponse = holder.getNodeValue("//a:Description")
```

Then create an Sql instance (import is groovy.sql.Sql) as ,

```
Sql sqlInstance = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPsswd, dbDriverClass)
    //Url e.g., - jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
    //driverClass e.g., - oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  
//dbUsername- username of the required db user  dbPsswd- password of the required db user 
   // This is what I use for oracle 11g

def result = sqlInstance.firstRow("Select Description from CountryTable where id='243'")  
   // if multiple  records, def result = sqlInstance.rows("Select Description from CountryTable where id='243'")


result.each {key, val ->
log.info key
log.info val
log.info val==descriptionFromResponse //true if the both matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know how to structure the test cases. If not please go through the [link](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html)

Create a  test suite -> test case

1. add the test request step that you are talking about
2. add another jdbc test step and get the detail that you wanted to verify the result against step1
3. add a groovy step : this will have get the responses of above both steps and traverse thru the nodes and compare the values. If every thing is fine it is ok, otherwise fail the test. Here you need to write some code in order to do the same.

You should be able to get the responses( of the first two steps) in 3 rd step using below script

```
import groovy.xml.*
def getResponse = {stepName ->
    def step = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(stepName)
    def response = new String(step.testRequest.messageExchange.response)
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
    xml
}

//provide name of the test steps for below two lines
def step1Response = getResponse('STEP1_NAME')
def step2XResponse = getResponse('STEP2_NAME')
```

Now required element values needs to be extracted and compared for both step1Response, step2Response

Comment: If you have the sample responses, probably will try to provide some sample groovy code.

Comment: <LoadCountriesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <LoadCountriesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ips.AML.Service.DataObjects.DataReference" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Country>
               <a:Description>AFGHANISTAN</a:Description>
               <a:Id>243</a:Id>
            </a:Country>
            <a:Country>
               <a:Description>ÄGYPTEN</a:Description>
               <a:Id>244</a:Id>
................an so on

Comment: What about the jdbc response to compared against? and fields to compare as there could be different elements from different response.

Comment: i want to check in Database. as i got response of countries and conrty id I want to cross check that in DB too.Response compared with DB stored data.Thanks